# Работа с vk api, qthread (PyQt5)

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api, pyqt5

Здравствуйте. У меня есть приложение, которое выполняет запрос к хранимой процедуре в вк, загружает эти данные в отдельном потоке QThread и помещает данные в таблицу. Проблема заключается в том, что приложение вылетает по неизвестной мне причине, отладка ничего не говорит, сам я уже многое пробовал менять в коде программы. Самое смешное, что это происходит периодически: в один день приложение вылетает, в другой нет (сохранял рабочий код, вводил те же входные данные, но приложение уже не работало). В хранимой процедуре выполняется менее чем 25 запросов к API. И еще: приложение в процессе работы (примерно на 9-30 % проделанной работы по ProgressBar). Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в чем проблема.

UPD: попробовал запустить приложение при закрытом браузере и приложение вылетело примерно на 50 %. Я подозреваю, что эта проблема связана с нагрузкой на сеть.

Вот отрывок кода из этого приложения:

```
def update(self, str1):
    str2 = json.loads(str1)
    for i in range(0, len(str2['response'])):
        self.tablewidget.insertRow(self.tablewidget.rowCount())
        print(str2['response'][i]['text'])
        self.tablewidget.setItem(self.tablewidget.rowCount()-1, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str2['response'][i]['text']))

def do_(self):

    if not(not self.text1.toPlainText() or self.text1.toPlainText().isspace() or not self.text2.toPlainText() or self.text2.toPlainText().isspace()):
        if self.progress.value()==100 or self.progress.value()==0:
            self.thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
            self.my = myClass()
            self.my.moveToThread(self.thread)

            self.thread.started.connect(self.my.User_find)
            self.my.finished.connect(self.thread.quit, QtCore.Qt.BlockingQueuedConnection)
            self.my.finished.connect(self.my.deleteLater, QtCore.Qt.BlockingQueuedConnection)
            self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater, QtCore.Qt.BlockingQueuedConnection)
            self.my.message.connect(self.update, QtCore.Qt.BlockingQueuedConnection)

            self.my.sendGlobalVar.connect(self.my.receiveID, QtCore.Qt.DirectConnection)
            self.my.sendGlobalVar.emit(self.text1.toPlainText(), self.text2.toPlainText())

            self.my.progress.connect(self.progress.setValue)

            self.thread.start()
        else: self.msg2.exec()
    else: self.msg1.exec()    

class myClass(QtCore.QObject):
 sendGlobalVar = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str)
 finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
 message = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
 progress = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

 globalVar1 = None
 globalVar2 = None

 def receiveID(self, txt1, txt2):
    global globalVar1
    global globalVar2
    globalVar1 = txt1
    globalVar2 = txt2            

 @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
 def User_find(self):
    for f in range(0, 100):
        url="https://api.vk.com/method/execute.getCommentsFromPosts?owner_id=%s&user_id=%s&offset=%s&v=5.60&access_token=..." % (globalVar1, globalVar2, f*4)
        self.message.emit(requests.get(url).text)
        self.progress.emit(f+1)
    self.finished.emit()
```

Comment: что значит вылетает? есть стектрейс?

Comment: @vadimvaduxa, стектрейса нет, под "вылетает" я имею в виду, что окно виджета само закрывается и программа завершается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для [вывода](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/incompatibilities.html#unhandled-python-exceptions) стектрейса, добавьте в `__main__`

```
def except_hook(*args):
    raise
sys.excepthook = except_hook
```

---

Посмотрите что в `str1` в момент ошибки, там не будет строки `'{ "response": [] }'`, которую вы ожидаете. А если так и предусмотрено, то можно сделать так `len(str2.get('response', []))`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736819/pyqt-no-error-msg-traceback-on-exit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581496/error-in-pyqt-qthread-not-printed

Comment: https://pp.vk.me/c637530/v637530428/3085a/aKtm8EEq3HA.jpg
Стектрейс появился, спасибо, только не понимаю пока что в чем проблема

Comment: курсовая не ваша видимо :) там написано Keyerror в str2['response']

Comment: нет, это моя курсовая, просто название ключа то правильное. У меня в ответ от хранимой процедуры в vk приходит json-строка вида:

{
"response": []
}

Я так понимаю программа не может считать длину этой строки.

Comment: в общем сделал обработку исключений, теперь вроде как не ругается и не вылетает, странная ошибка, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51660/discussion-between-ramil-and-vadim-vaduxa).